# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una lista para un dropdownlist a una vista por ViewBag en ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Lo he intentado vía ViewBag que es lo que siempre he usado pero no he tenido éxito en MVC 5 ASP.Net.
Lo que quiero es llenar el combobox a base de una lista llenada en mi Controller, así:

```
namespace AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ANAQUEL
    {
        public ANAQUEL()
        {
            this.DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL = new HashSet<DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL>();
        }

        public int NIDANAQUEL { get; set; }
        public int NIDALMACEN { get; set; }
        public string SCODANAQUEL { get; set; }
        public string SDESANAQUEL { get; set; }
        public int NESTADO { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DFECREG { get; set; }
        public string SUSUREG { get; set; }

        public virtual ALMACEN ALMACEN { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL> DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades;
using AcisacWeb.Web.Core.Mantenimiento;

namespace Acisac.Controllers
{
    public class MantenimientoController : Controller
    {

        AlmacenCore AlmacenCore = new AlmacenCore();
        AnaquelCore AnaquelCore = new AnaquelCore();
        ClienteCore ClienteCore = new ClienteCore();
        ProductoCore ProductoCore = new ProductoCore();
        UnidadCore UnidadCore = new UnidadCore();

public ActionResult AnaquelesNuevo()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AnaquelesNuevo(ANAQUEL a)
        {
            ViewBag.almacenes = new SelectList(AlmacenCore.ListarCompleto(), "NIDALMACEN", "SDESALMACEN");

            a.SCODANAQUEL = "x";

            a.SUSUREG = "jgarcia";
            a.NESTADO = 1;

            if (AnaquelCore.Agregar(a) == true)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Anaqueles");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AnaquelesNuevo");
            }

        }
```

---

```
@model AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades.ANAQUEL

@{
    Layout = null;
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="valor" class="control-label">Nombre</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SDESANAQUEL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SDESANAQUEL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="valor" class="control-label">Almacén</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("almacenes", (SelectList)ViewBag.almacenes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control btn-block" } })
            </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Guardar">

                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                    Cancelar
                </button>
            </div>



    }
```

He querido depurar poniendo un punto de interrupción en mi Capa de Datos pero tampoco puedo,me va defrente a la vista.

Comment: En vez de asignar un SelectList, intenta asignado un IEnumerable<SelectListItem> al `ViewBag.almanaces` asi: `ViewBag.almacenes = AlmacenCore.ListarCompleto();` Me parece que DropDownList recibe una enumeracion de `SelectListItem`, no un `SelectList` pero no tengo como comprobarlo ahora.

Comment: Por cierto, `AlmacenCore.ListarCompleto()` retorna `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, verdad?

Comment: Hola ! revisa mi respuesta que te deje más abajo. Saludos !

Answer (score 2):

Dado tu comentario que al cambiar el nombre del `DropDownList` no te funcionó, entonces cambiaremos la forma en que se llena el `ViewBag.almacenes` llenando un `List<SelectListItem>` desde el Controller.

Código del Controller:

```
ViewBag.almacenes = AlmacenCore.ListarCompleto().Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Value = p.NIDALMACEN.ToString(), Text = p.SDESALMACEN }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

Código del View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NIDALMACEN, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.almacenes, "Seleccione un almacén", new { @class = "form-control btn-block" })
```

Comment: lamentablemente lo intenté antes y también ahora pero nada :/

Comment: @J.Carlos Vale, entonces debemos cambiar también la forma en que llenas el `ViewBag.almacenes`

Comment: disculpa,de qué forma?

Comment: @J.Carlos listo, he actualizado mi respuesta, revisad ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es muy extraño, he limpiado,compilado y ejecutado y sigue sin andar :/ . Dice : No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' con la clave 'NIDALMACEN'.

Comment: @J.Carlos me parece extraño, ¿así se llama la propiedad del índice al llenar la lista de almacenes, cierto?

Comment: @J.Carlos ya sé qué pasa, en tu modelo, ¿cómo se llama que quieres mapear a esta lista de almacenes?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que quiero hacer un formulario para el registro de un anaquel. En el formulario quiero indicar que un anaquel pertenece a un respectivo almacen para eso necesito el combobox de todos los almacenes. PD: he adjuntado mi modelo (Generado con EntityFramework)

Comment: @J.Carlos wow, eso síque es bastante extraño, en tu modelo sí tienes la propiedad `NIDALMACEN`, justo así como está el código debería funcionar :/ intenta limpiando la solución y volver a compilar ;)

Comment: Hola @Phi me gusta tu respuesta la utilice y me funciono a la perfección pero tengo una duda en en controlador en la parte de Text, ¿es posible que el valor dado a text sea una concatenacion de dos elementos de la misma entidad ?, por ejemplo si mandaramos una lista persona en value seria igual al id en Text podemos poner algo como  `Text = p.Nombre+" "+p.apellido` , por dar un ejemplo, espero tu respuesta y muchas gracias

Comment: Claro que sí @Oscar, puedes poner lo que gustes para ponerlo en el `Text`, justo tal cual como lo pusiste en tu comentario

Comment: @Phi de hecho lo intente y me funciono, muchas gracias ese fragmento de código me esta sacando de varios apuros

Answer (score 0):

utiliza el helperhtml DropdownList a tu ViewBag ponle el mismo nombre que tiene el Atributo de la clase ejemplo:

```
  //Controller
  ViewBag.NIDALMACEN = new SelectList(AlmacenCore.ListarCompleto(), "NIDALMACEN", "SDESALMACEN");


  //View
  @Html.DropDownList("NIDALMACEN", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

En el controlador debes obtener los datos que vas a llenar en tu lista y asignarlos a un `ViewBag.CualquierNombre` como el siguiente código.

```
ViewBag.List =  new SelectList(sucursalOut.data, "idSucursal", "nombreSucursal");
```

En donde genero una lista de tipo `SelectList` donde le paso como primer parametro los datos que debo listar, seguido del campo o la `property` del `id` junto con el nombre de mi `property` en este caso el nombre de mi sucursal.

En tu vista debes llamar al `ViewBag.List` de la siguiente forma:

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdSucursal", ViewBag.List as SelectList, "Seleccione Sucursal", new { @class = "form-control w-100" })
```

Para finalmente renderizar un campo `<select>`

Espero que mi respuesta te pueda ayudar, al igual que a los demas. Saludos ! (: